# Hashtable Duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

i have this hashtable that i am converting to dictionary on the same line

```
Hashtable ids = new Hashtable();

ids = new Hashtable(_AppContext.TBL_PERSON.Where(oItem => oItem.DELETED == false).ToDictionary(o => o.CODE.ToUpper(), o => o.PERSON_ID));
```

thing is i am getting an error

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

after Checking rows it turns out that CODE column has same row value multiple times.
is there a way to select only first value that occurs like First() but without making it first datatable then changing it to hashtable ?

Comment: Why are you wanting a `Hashtable`? `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<T,U>` is preferable.

Comment: Also you can pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as the `IEqualityComporer<T>` instance  to the `ToDictionary` call so that any lookups or additions of/to the dictionary are case insensitive by default. That saves you having to do ToUpper with every new key or with a lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - use `GroupBy` and then pick the `First()` object in the group for the value:

```
ids = new Hashtable(
        _AppContext.TBL_PERSON.Where(oItem => oItem.DELETED == false)
                              .GroupBy(o => o.CODE.ToUpper())
                              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().PERSON_ID)
       );
```

Keep in mind this gives you a HashTable of `KeyValuePair<T,U>` objects, which seems odd. If you just want the dictionary you can still use `GroupBy` and just remove the outer `HashTable` creation.

Comment: Thanks, it works, it might be odd but it returns the hashtable to another page that i haven't worked on so changing it will result to change a lot of other things, but this solution works brilliant